# Is it Amekakure or Amegakure?

Tags: pronunciation, readings, rendaku

In Naruto the village hidden in rain is called Amegakure in English Version and Pronounced like "Ame-ga-kure" in both Japanese and English Version.
But if you try to translate the kanji of this 雨隠れの里 to English(Google Translate), we get "Ame kakure no sato" as the translation.
So I was just wondering what is the correct spelling of it. Can someone help?

Comment: Honestly the lesson here is never to use Google Translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are downvoted, because I think this is an excellent question! Sometimes, when two words in Japanese combines, the beginning of the second word changes and gets `゛` (濁点.)

雨 (あめ) 隠れ (かくれ) is a good one, because I'd read it as "ama-gakure", so not only does "ka" get 濁点 but "ame" also changes to "ama."

Here are some other examples, including my own name:

- 手(て)+紙(かみ) → 手紙(てがみ)
- 川(かわ)+口(くち) → 川口(かわぐち)
- 鼻(はな)+血(ち) → 鼻血(はなぢ)

As a native speaker, I know when to do this instinctively, to the point that it feels awkward to pronounce if I don't do it, but [according to wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E6%BF%81), the rule apparently isn't entirely logical and deterministic(!)